# Problems with second display

Tags: display

First of all this problem is only with KDE.
Im configuring my displays with nvidia-settings. I set to both right Hz and resolution
But on second display allways there is some line that is separate moving objects, like when i move window arround the screen some line moving from buttom to top of the screen. Ths is very bad at movies :(
Before few minutes i made a photo with my DSLR on high speed when moving an object on second display: http://postimage.org/image/bspv69jzr/

Please help :)